# Can I have rhythmbox integration on dash in 11.10?

Tags: unity-dash, rhythmbox, lenses

Dash in 11.10 version uses banshee music database for searching music in the music lens. Can I do sth similar with Rhythmbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these program that you see up are your Default Applications.
(System Settings / System Info) then on the left you'll see Default Applications.
Just change your default Music: to Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 3):

The default music lens works only with Banshee's database, but there are community packages that support rhythmbox (see for example https://launchpad.net/~markjtully/+archive/ppa/+packages)